# Java - Switch functionality

Tags: java, switch-statement

Down bellow is part of a code that calculates how many vowels a word has. The first code does the same thing as the second right? So, if i want to use several cases with the same operations, i just need to put the operation on the last one (Like in the first code)?

First:

```
public static int contvowel(String pal){ 
        int cont=0; 
        pal=pal.toLowerCase(); 
        for(int i=0; i<pal.length();i++) { 
            switch(pal.charAt(i)){ 
                case 'a': 
                case 'e': 
                case 'i': 
                case 'o': 
                case 'u': { cont=cont+1; break; }
            } 
        } 
            return cont; 
        }
```

Second:

```
public static int contvowel(String pal){ 
        int cont=0; 
        pal=pal.toLowerCase(); 
        for(int i=0; i<pal.length();i++) { 
            switch(pal.charAt(i)){ 
                case 'a': cont=cont+1; break;
                case 'e': cont=cont+1; break;
                case 'i': cont=cont+1; break;
                case 'o': cont=cont+1; break;
                case 'u': cont=cont+1; break;
            } 
        } 
            return cont; 
        }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Try running it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want to be sure about it.

Comment: If you run it and it works, you can be pretty solidly sure about it without asking anyone else.

Comment: Isn't `'y'` considered as a vowel?

Comment: @JBNizet: *Sometimes*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, the original variables are not in english. Cont is the abreviation for the portuguese word "contador" which means "counter". I just changed it a bit to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Exsound: Ah! There I go with my language blinders on. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, "yes" - the outcome is the same.

---

But here's some food for thought:

```
public static int countVowels(String pal) { 
    return pal.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();
}
```

Comment: I'd choose a slightly longer, but more efficient regex idiom (a `find()` loop).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But the code density of a one-line solution is so yummy!

Comment: Agreed :) and if it's not on a critical code path, why not :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I would be comfortable to write that code and commit it to prod and then get on with doing something else asap. I would only think about "optimising" it (either for readability or performance) if there was a proven issue.

Comment: Unless you'd be processing multi-MB strings this way, the chance of a bottleneck is indeed very small. It's just that my tastes have wandered away from concise towards fast. I like the code to strike a good balance between those two and especially dislike code which uses an open-ended amount of memory, possibly even OOME-ing on very large inputs. I take that into account even when solving problems known to be of small size.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is:

Yes. The first code is the same as the second.

Comment: And note that the `{...}` under the `case` are completely unnecessary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As well as the `break`

Comment: @still_learning: Yes, but the `break` is good practice (to avoid laying a trap for the maintenance programmer who comes along later). The `{...}` doesn't add anything (unless you're declaring variables inside it, in which case you really need to write a separate function).

Answer (score 0):

**YES** the *outcome* and the *result* will be the same. But defenitly **NO** for "The code  makes the same".

EDIT: like mentioned in the comments, these are the two compiled versions:

Version 1:

```
Compiled from "Hello.java"
public class main.java.Hello {
  public main.java.Hello();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String Hello, World!
       2: astore_1      
       3: iconst_0      
       4: istore_2      
       5: aload_1       
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.toLowerCase:()Ljava/lang/String;
       9: astore_1      
      10: iconst_0      
      11: istore_3      
      12: iload_3       
      13: aload_1       
      14: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
      17: if_icmpge     86
      20: aload_1       
      21: iload_3       
      22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.charAt:(I)C
      25: lookupswitch  { // 5
                    97: 76
                   101: 76
                   105: 76
                   111: 76
                   117: 76
               default: 80
          }
      76: iload_2       
      77: iconst_1      
      78: iadd          
      79: istore_2      
      80: iinc          3, 1
      83: goto          12
      86: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      89: new           #7                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      92: dup           
      93: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      96: ldc           #9                  // String Got: 
      98: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     101: iload_2       
     102: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     105: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     108: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     111: return        
}
```

Version 2:

```
Compiled from "Hello.java"
public class main.java.Hello {
  public main.java.Hello();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String Hello, World!
       2: astore_1      
       3: iconst_0      
       4: istore_2      
       5: aload_1       
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.toLowerCase:()Ljava/lang/String;
       9: astore_1      
      10: iconst_0      
      11: istore_3      
      12: iload_3       
      13: aload_1       
      14: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
      17: if_icmpge     114
      20: aload_1       
      21: iload_3       
      22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.charAt:(I)C
      25: lookupswitch  { // 5
                    97: 76
                   101: 83
                   105: 90
                   111: 97
                   117: 104
               default: 108
          }
      76: iload_2       
      77: iconst_1      
      78: iadd          
      79: istore_2      
      80: goto          108
      83: iload_2       
      84: iconst_1      
      85: iadd          
      86: istore_2      
      87: goto          108
      90: iload_2       
      91: iconst_1      
      92: iadd          
      93: istore_2      
      94: goto          108
      97: iload_2       
      98: iconst_1      
      99: iadd          
     100: istore_2      
     101: goto          108
     104: iload_2       
     105: iconst_1      
     106: iadd          
     107: istore_2      
     108: iinc          3, 1
     111: goto          12
     114: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     117: new           #7                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
     120: dup           
     121: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     124: ldc           #9                  // String Got: 
     126: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     129: iload_2       
     130: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     133: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     136: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     139: return        
}
```

**diff -e ou1 ou2**

```
39,51c
      80: goto          108
      83: iload_2       
      84: iconst_1      
      85: iadd          
      86: istore_2      
      87: goto          108
      90: iload_2       
      91: iconst_1      
      92: iadd          
      93: istore_2      
      94: goto          108
      97: iload_2       
      98: iconst_1      
      99: iadd          
     100: istore_2      
     101: goto          108
     104: iload_2       
     105: iconst_1      
     106: iadd          
     107: istore_2      
     108: iinc          3, 1
     111: goto          12
     114: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     117: new           #7                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
     120: dup           
     121: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     124: ldc           #9                  // String Got: 
     126: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     129: iload_2       
     130: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     133: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     136: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     139: return        
.
29,33c
                   101: 83
                   105: 90
                   111: 97
                   117: 104
               default: 108
.
23c
      17: if_icmpge     114
```

Comment: You probably should compile both and look at what `javac` actually emits as bytecode before saying "Definitely no". :-) And even if `javac` doesn't combine the identical clauses, you can be sure HotSpot (Sun/Oracle's JVM) will if the code runs more than a couple of times. *Edit*: Wow, `javac` doesn't combine them.